# Element is not hiding

Tags: jquery, meteor

Element is not hiding. I'm using jQuery to do that.
I've got this lines in my .html file

```
<template name="index">
   <div class="main">
      //Here some "main" code
   </div>
   <div class="testing">
      //Here some "testing" code
   </div>
   {{hide}}
</template>
```

And i want to hide "testing" via jQuery.
In client/client.js i've got that:

```
Template.index.hide = function(){
$(".testing").hide();
}
```

And it doesn't work:C. jQuery connected to this page*
Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any errors in your console? Where are you calling `Template.index.hide`?

Comment: @ruwest: take a look to my answer... if you have problems with jquery, try ti hide via css or html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

**jQuery**

```
 $(function () {
   $(".testing").hide();
   $(".testing").css({'display':'none'});
});
```

**VIA CSS**

```
.testing{display:none;}
```

OR

**VIA HTML**

```
<div class="testing" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `hide().trigger('hide');`

Also, the code won't execute unless you call `Template.index.hide();`.